# Hook into OWIN controller creation in c#

Tags: c#, controller, hook, owin, factory

Is it possible, to hook into the OWIN self hosted controller factory? I want to decide which controller should be created for a request.

I searched a lot but could not find exactly what i am looking for. All method i found hook into the wrong place of the Owin pipeline.

**EDIT**

The ASP.Net `ControllerBuilder` seems not to work: `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(CustomControllerFactory));`.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're speaking about the WebAPI 2 controller factory, what you want to do is actually pretty easy; you just have to provide the `HttpConfiguration` of your WebAPI with a custom set of helpers which you'll teach your "rules".

What you need to supply (probably):

- a `IHttpControllerTypeResolver` which which is responsible to discover the types matching the controller definition (type-wise... for example if you'd like to suppress the "Controller" suffix required in the class name).
- a `IHttpControllerSelector` where you can implement your custom controller/action selection rules.

You'd probably want to provide custom `IAssembliesResolver` and `IHttpControllerActivator` too for your own full-blown and flexible DI solution.

Comment: Yep, thank you, that is now working already. My problem now is, that i want to extend my web api 2 with IronPython classes. The problem is, that IP-Classes are not full qulified Clr-Classes. So the type i return in the `IHttpControlelrTypeResolver` is not valid. But thank you! Your question answered the asked question!

Comment: I found the subsequent question you asked ;) Interesting topic!

Comment: Yep, if i solve this problem, we should have a nice tool for writing dynamic web apis in python :)